# viewing the arrays in my printArray method

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, methods, polymorphism

My code in my printArray method viewing the arrays in my printArray method:

```
    public class arrayTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Integer[] list1 = {12, 43, 56, 72};
    Double[] list2 = {12.5, 45.6, 62.4, 65.8};
    String[] list3 = {"1", "2", "3"};

    printArray(list1);
    printArray(list2);
    printArray(list3);

}

public static void printArray(Object[] list){
          Object o = list;
          System.out.println(o);
    }
```

This doesn't show the array. What mistakes I have made?

Comment: This code compiles if one more `}` is added at the end of this code. What is your problem?

Comment: Are you trying to show each individual value in the array? If so, I would use a for loop or a "for each" loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the output you will get, 
as you are doing `Object o = list;` And then printing `object o`.

```
[Ljava.lang.Integer;@106d69c
[Ljava.lang.Double;@52e922
[Ljava.lang.String;@25154f
```

You can directly print the objects without assigning it to any object.

Your modified code :

```
class arrayTest {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Integer[] list1 = {12, 43, 56, 72};
    Double[] list2 = {12.5, 45.6, 62.4, 65.8};
    String[] list3 = {"1", "2", "3"};

    printArray(list1);
    printArray(list2);
    printArray(list3);

}

public static void printArray(Object[] list){
         for(Object o : list)
            System.out.println(o);
    }}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use "for each":

```
public static void printArray(Object[] list)
{
     for(Object item : list)
     {
       System.out.println(item);
     } //end for
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void printArray(Object[] list){
         for(int i=0; i<list.length;i++)
          System.out.println(list[i]);
    }
}
```

you are assigning the array named list to Object. you just need to iterate on the list and print it.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer inbuilt method **toString(array)** of **java.util.Arrays** class (provided array is of simple data types). It saves extra lines of code than writing loops.

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
Arrays.toString(arr);// just a single line
```

output:
[1, 2, 3 ,4, 5]